# Determine if active directory user started application

Tags: java, windows, dns

I would like to find out if and which active directory user started my windows java application.

I can't use `System.getProperty("user.name")`/`System.getenv("USERDOMAIN")` because security reasons.

`Advapi32Util.getUserName()` and `NTSystem.getName()` only seem to return the local user, but not the active directory user who started the application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can execute cmd command and get the output (if your security will allow that).

```
public static String executeCmdCommand(String command) 
{
    String result = null;
    try (var inputStream = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream();
            var s = new Scanner(inputStream)) 
    {
        result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : null;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Objects.requireNonNullElse(result, "").trim();
}
```

Then, executeCmdCommand("whoami") will return "domain/username"

Comment: But doesn't that only return the currently logged-in user? But not the active directory user who started the program?